# Compiler code error : 'a' was not declared

Tags: compiler-errors

Ok. Trying to generate a code by displaying the stack contents after each instruction where we assume that the variables are initialized with the values: a=22, b=33 and c=44

Also, assume the following address environment:

```
ρ={a I→5,b I→6,cI→7}
```

My background: 4th day of Compiler Design and Virtual Machines. New to this stuff and evidently this is not C++, but something else. Prog is VERY "hands off", especially current prof.

```
int main (void)  {
a = 22
b = 33`
c = 44
p = {'a' : 5, 'b' : 6, 'c' : 7}
for each instruction in the generated code:
if instruction.startswith ('a'): 
p['a'] = instruction[1]
elif instruction.startswith ('b'):
p['b'] = instruction[1]
elif instruction.startswith ('c'):
p['c'] = instruction[1]
print (f'a = {p['a']},  b = {p['b']}, c = {p['c']}')
     }
```

#### To be honest, I was expecting it to compile and return back a = 22, b = 33, and c = 44??

#### Got back a few errors:

#### main.cpp:12:9: warning: character constant too long for its type

#### 12 | print (f'a = {p['a']},  b = {p['b']}, c = {p['c']}')

#### |         ^~~~~~~~~~

---

#### main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

#### main.cpp:2:1: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope

#### 2 | a = 22

#### | ^

---

#### main.cpp: At global scope

#### 6 | if instruction.startswith ('a'):

#### | ^~

#### main.cpp:13:6: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token

#### 13 |      }

#### |      ^

Comment: Where do you think you declared it?

Comment: Scott, yes, I am thinking I declared it lines 2 to 4, a = 22, etc ???

Comment: Your compiler (which you failed to identify) does not agree.  The fact that this is a .cpp file suggests you are using a C++ compiler, but this is NOT valid C++ code.

Comment: Ok, using GDB (onlinegdb.com), ok, thus, either change complier or proper C++ code? Thanks a million, John